# ENVIO DE DATOS DE FORMULARIO A VARIAS TABLAS

Tags: php, mysql

alguien que ayude con el scrip php para poder insertar los datos a mysql de mi formulario a varias tablas relacionadas

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>INSCRIPCIÓN-ADMISIÓN UNTRM</title>
    <link rel="Icon" href="img/favicon.jpg">
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/fuentes.css">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>

    <!--barra-->
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <a href="index.html" class="brand-logo"><img src="img/logo-untrm.svg" style="width:300px; margin-top:5px; margin-left:10px; "></a>
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a href="https://untrm.edu.pe/es/">Portal universitario</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--contenedor-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12" style="padding-left:250px; ">
                    <h4>FICHA DE INSCRIPCIÓN</h4>
                </div>

            </div>
            <form class="col s12" method="POST" action="insertar.php" name="myform">

                <ul class="collapsible">
                    <li class="active">
                        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>Datos Personales</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body"><span>
                                <!--datos del postulante-->
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                                        <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate" name="aparteno">
                                        <label for="last_name">Apellido Paterno</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                                        <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate" name="amaterno">
                                        <label for="last_name">Apellido materno</label>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                                        <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate" name="anombres">
                                        <label for="last_name">Nombres</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                                        <input id="last_name" type="number" class="validate" name="aedad">
                                        <label for="last_name">Edad</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                                        <input id="last_name" type="date" class="validate" name="afnacimiento">
                                        <label for="last_name">Fecha De Nacimiento</label>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="row">

                                    <div class="input-field col s4">
                                        <select class="browser-default" name="psexo">
                                            <option value="" disabled selected>Sexo</option>
                                            <option value="1">M</option>
                                            <option value="2">H</option>

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-field col s4">
                                        <select class="browser-default" name="ecivil">
                                            <option value="" disabled selected>Estado Civil</option>
                                            <option value="1">Soltero</option>
                                            <option value="2">Conviviente</option>
                                            <option value="3">Casado</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-field col s4">
                                        <input id="last_name" type="number" class="validate" name="adni">
                                        <label for="last_name">DNI</label>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </span></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Lugar De Nacimiento</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body"><span>
                                <!--lugar de nacimiento-->
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                                        <input id="ubi_name" type="text" class="validate" name="lndepartamento">
                                        <label for="ubi_name">Departamento</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                                        <input id="ubi_name" type="text" class="validate" name="lnprovincia">
                                        <label for="ubi_name">Provincia</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                                        <input id="ubi_name" type="text" class="validate" name="lndistrito">
                                        <label for="ubi_name">Distrito</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </span></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">home</i>Lugar De Residencia
                            Actual</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body"><span>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                                        <input id="ubiac_name" type="text" class="validate" name="lrdepartamento">
                                        <label for="ubiac_name">Departamento</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                                        <input id="ubiac_name" type="text" class="validate" name="lrprovincia">
                                        <label for="ubiac_name">Provincia</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                                        <input id="ubiac_name" type="text" class="validate" name="lrdistrito">
                                        <label for="ubiac_name">Distrito</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                                        <input id="ubiac_name" type="text" class="validate" name="lrdireccion">
                                        <label for="ubiac_name">Dirección Actual</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </span></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">local_phone</i>Información De
                            Contacto</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body"><span>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                                        <input id="email" type="email" class="validate" name="icemail">
                                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                                        <input id="last_name" type="number" class="validate" name="iccelular">
                                        <label for="last_name">Numero De Celular</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                                        <input id="last_name" type="number" class="validate" name="icwhatsapp">
                                        <label for="last_name">Numero De Whatsapp</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                                        <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate" name="icfacebook">
                                        <label for="last_name">Facebook</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </span></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">local_library</i>Colegio Secundario
                            De Procedencia</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body"><span>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                                        <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate" name="csnombre">
                                        <label for="last_name">Nombre del colegio secundario</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-field col s6">

                                        <select class="browser-default" name="cstipo">
                                            <option value="" disabled selected>Tipo de colegio</option>
                                            <option value="1">Público</option>
                                            <option value="2">privado</option>

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col s4">
                                        <input id="ubi_name" type="text" class="validate" name="csdepartamento">
                                        <label for="ubi_name">Departamento</label>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="input-field col s4">
                                        <input id="ubi_name" type="text" class="validate" name="csprovincia">
                                        <label for="ubi_name">Provincia</label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="input-field col s4">
                                        <input id="ubi_name" type="text" class="validate" name="csdistrito">
                                        <label for="ubi_name">Distrito</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </span></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">local_parking</i>Tipo De Preparación
                            Academica</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body"><span>
                                <p>
                                    <label>
                                        <input class="with-gap" name="apre" type="radio"  />
                                        <span>Academia Privada</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                        <input class="with-gap" name="apre" type="radio" />
                                        <span>Cepre UNTRM</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                        <input class="with-gap" name="apre" type="radio" />
                                        <span>Profesor Particular</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                        <input class="with-gap" name="apre" type="radio" />
                                        <span>Ninguna</span>
                                    </label>

                                </p>

                            </span></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">border_color</i>Carrera A Postular</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body"><span>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col s3">
                                        <select class="browser-default" name="pcarrera">
                                            <option value="" disabled selected>CHACHAPOYAS</option>
                                            <option value="1">Derecho y ciencias políticas</option>
                                            <option value="2">Psicología </option>
                                            <option value="3">Medicina humana </option>
                                            <option value="4">Ingeniería agrónoma </option>
                                            <option value="5">Ingeniería zootecnista </option>
                                            <option value="6">Ingeniería civil </option>
                                            <option value="7">Antropología </option>
                                            <option value="8">Ciencias de la comunicación </option>
                                            <option value="9">Enfermería </option>
                                            <option value="10">Estomatología </option>
                                            <option value="11">Administración en turismo </option>
                                            <option value="12">Administración de empresas </option>

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-field col s3">
                                        <select class="browser-default" name="pcarrera">
                                            <option value="" disabled selected>BAGUA</option>
                                            <option value="1">Ingeniería de sistemas</option>
                                            <option value="2">Administración en turismo </option>
                                            <option value="3">Administración de empresas </option>

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-field col s3">
                                        <select class="browser-default" name="pcarrera">
                                            <option value="" disabled selected>RODRIGUEZ DE MENDOZA</option>
                                            <option value="1">Administración en turismo </option>
                                            <option value="2">Administración de empresas </option>

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-field col s3">
                                        <select class="browser-default" name="pcarrera">
                                            <option value="" disabled selected>UTCUBAMBA</option>
                                            <option value="1">Administración en turismo</option>

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </span></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">domain</i>Elige La Sede Donde
                            Postularas</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body"><span>
                                <p>
                                    <label>
                                        <input class="with-gap" name="asede" type="radio" />
                                        <span>CHACHAPOYAS</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                        <input class="with-gap" name="asede" type="radio" />
                                        <span>BAGUA</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                        <input class="with-gap" name="asede" type="radio" />
                                        <span>RODRIGUEZ DE MENDOZA</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                        <input class="with-gap" name="asede" type="radio" />
                                        <span>UTCUBAMBA</span>
                                    </label>

                                </p>

                            </span></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!--envio de datos-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s12" style="padding-left: 90%">
                        <button onclick="javascript:validate();" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit"
                            name="action">ENVIAR
                            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                        </button>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </form>
        </div>



    </div>


    <!--pie de pagina-->
    <footer class="page-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="footer-copyright">
                <div class="container">

                    <a class="grey-text text-lighten-4 left" href="#!" style="margin-left: 200px;">© 2018 Copyright
                        UNTRM</a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </footer>




    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
            var instances = M.Collapsible.init(elems);
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        function validate() {
            var allright = true;
            if (allright == true) {
  
  alert("haz completado correcto");
location.href ="index.html"
}else {
  alert('Algunos campos no están llenos de la manera correcta, vuelva a revisarlos');
}
return allright;
}
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

codigo php

```html
<?php
include("conexion.php");

//datos del formulario
//datos personales
$aparteno = $_POST['aparteno'];
$amarterno = $_POST['amaterno'];
$anombres = $_POST['anombres'];
$aedad = $_POST['aedad'];
$afnacimiento = $_POST['afnacimiento'];
$psexo = $_POST['psexo'];
$ecivil = $_POST['ecivil'];
$adni = $_POST['adni'];
//Lugar De Nacimiento
$lndepartamento = $_POST['lndepartamento'];
$lnprovincia = $_POST['lnprovincia'];
$lndistrito = $_POST['lndistrito'];
//Lugar De Residencia
$lrdepartamento = $_POST['lrdepartamento'];
$lrprovincia = $_POST['lrprovincia'];
$lrdistrito = $_POST['lrdistrito'];
$lrdireccion = $_POST['lrdireccion'];
//Información De Contacto
$icemail = $_POST['icemail'];
$iccelular = $_POST['iccelular'];
$icwhatsapp = $_POST['icwhatsapp'];
$icfacebook = $_POST['icfacebook'];
//Colegio Secundario De Procedencia
$csnombre = $_POST['csnombre'];
$cstipo = $_POST['cstipo'];
$csdepartamento = $_POST['csdepartamento'];
$csprovincia = $_POST['csprovincia'];
$csdistrito = $_POST['csdistrito'];
//Tipo De Preparación Academica
$apre = $_POST['apre'];
//Carrera A Postular
$pcarrera= $_POST['pcarrera'];
//Elige La Sede Donde Postularas
$asede = $_POST['asede'];

//insertar datos en las tablas


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

para la conexion con mysql te recomiendo usar la clase "mysqli" de php

para conectarse a la tabla puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect("ip", "userBD", "passBD", "nombre BD");
if(!$conexion){
 // aqui tu codigo de error 
}
if(mysqli_real_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO mybase (anombres,aedad) VALUES ($anombres,$aedad);")){
// si devuelve true es por que el query fue exitoso
// a traves de metodos como mysqli_use_result 

 $queryResult = mysqli_use_result($conexion); // este devuelve los resultados en la var queryResult 

// finalmente con mysqli_fetch_row recorres los rows

 while($r = mysqli_fetch_row($queryResult)){

  // r es un array de los campos que tenes en el row ej: r[0] r[1]
  // cabe aclarar que generalmente el insert no tiene una respuesta mas que el ultimo id insertado en la tabla.

 }
}

mysqli_close($conexion); // finalmente no te olvides de cerrar la conexion
```

Adicionalmente si quieres hacer varios insert de una sola puedes remplazar el real_query por mysqli_multi_query

solo le pasas las consultas concatenadas en un string EJ:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM myBD1;';
$query .= 'SELECT * FROM myBD2;';

mysqli_multi_query($query);
```

//////////ADICION//////

```
//para el insert: ejemplo de producto y venta:
//teniendo en cuenta estas dos tablas
| Tabla Producto    | Tabla Venta                 |
|prodID | prodNombre| ventaID | prodID | clienteID|
|  1    | manzana   |   1     |   1    | 1        |

teniendo en cuenta las dos tablas presentadas y que la clave foranea es prodID en la tabla Ventas un punto a tener en cuenta
1) si la clave foranea es inexistente saltara un error que impedira la operacion 

$query = 'INSERT INTO Ventas (prodID,clienteID) VALUES (1,1);';
$query = 'INSERT INTO Ventas (prodID,clienteID) VALUES (1,2);';

if (mysqli_multi_query($conexion, $query)) {
 do {

    if ($result = mysqli_store_result($link)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
         // los rows de tu tabla : row[0],row[1] 
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
  } while (mysqli_next_result($conexion));
}
// para hacerte el ejemplo me he basado en el php manual mas especificamente : http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php
// y http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php
// y recuerda que el insert no retorna si a mucho el insertid correspondiente a la ultima operacion de insert

| Tabla Producto    | Tabla Venta                 |
|prodID | prodNombre| ventaID | prodID | clienteID|
|  1    | manzana   |   1     |   1    | 1        |
                    |   2     |   1    | 1        |
                    |   3     |   1    | 2        |

si llegase el caso tu indicas en el INSERT un prodID diferente a 1 ( ya que es el unico que existe) la operacion del INSERT devolvera un error.
fuera de eso todo es igual :)
```

Saludos y buena energia :)

Comment: si no es mucha molestia, podria aser un ejemplo del script para llenar varias tablas con los insert --- gracias por su respuesta

Comment: claro amigo, con gusto, te refieres a la instruccion de insert? o el uso del mysqli_multi_query en php?

Comment: me funciono amigo gracias

Comment: amigo como seria el script  php si en mi tabla existen llaves foraneas? agradeceria tu repuesta

Comment: Me alegra poder ayudarte, con el tema de las llaves foraneas debemos tener en cuenta que la unica condicion es que el identificador ingresado en la instruccion INSERT de la llave foranea debe existir, de lo contrario mysql saltara un error que no dejara ejecutar la operacion, es decir, si ingresas un identificador que referencia a un item no existente en la tabla "padre" te dira que el registro no existe, no recuerdo exactamente el codigo del error.

Saludos y buena energia :) no olvides marcar la solucion, por si mas compañeros tienen la misma duda.

Comment: prodrias aser ejemplo seria de  gran ayuda

Comment: añadi el ejemplo a la respuesta para completar el contenido :) saludos y buena energia

Comment: gracias por el aporte